# How to make on hover TextBlock foreground change?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm pretty new in xaml) I finally managed to change on hover the background of a row. But I have the requirement also to change text color. I have this XAML code:

```
       <GridView
            Grid.Row="2"
            Padding="0,66,0,0"
            cm:Message.Attach="[Event ItemClick] = [OnCartItemSelected($clickedItem)]"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ImageGridView_CategoryItemContainerStyle}"
            ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ImageGridView_ItemsPanelTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ItemsInCart, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectionMode="None">


            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ItemInCart">

                    <Grid
                        Width="760"
                        PointerEntered="OnPointerEntered"
                        PointerExited="OnPointerExited">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="450" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Width="100"
                                Height="100"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Source="{x:Bind Item.ThumbnailPath, Mode=OneWay}"
                                Stretch="Uniform" />
                        </StackPanel>


                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1.5*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock x:Name="itemName"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                FontFamily="OpenSans"
                                FontSize="32"
                                FontStyle="Normal"
                                FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                Foreground="#FF4E4E4E"
                                LineHeight="34"
                                Text="{x:Bind Item.ItemName}"
                                TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                FontFamily="OpenSans"
                                FontSize="32"
                                FontStyle="Normal"
                                FontWeight="Normal"
                                Foreground="#FF4E4E4E"
                                Text="{x:Bind Item.ItemPriceWithCurrencySymbl}" />
                        </Grid>

                        <StackPanel
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Orientation="Horizontal">

                            <Image Width="25" Source="../Assets/Images/Pages/Cart/multiplication-sign.svg" />

                            <TextBlock
                                x:Name="amount"
                                Width="100"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                FontFamily="OpenSans"
                                FontSize="56"
                                FontStyle="Normal"
                                FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                Foreground="#FF4E4E4E"
                                Text="{x:Bind Amount}"
                                TextAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>


                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

and styles:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <controls:DataGridCell x:Key="DataGrid_RemovedDefaultCellFocus">
        <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridCell">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </controls:DataGridCell>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ImageGridView_ItemsPanelTemplate">
        <ItemsWrapGrid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="ImageGridView_CategoryItemContainerStyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border
                            x:Name="Border"
                            Margin="3"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" />
                        </Border>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#26b791" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

How to change TextBlock foreground of "amount" "itemName" on hover??

PS sorry for this big amount of code( System doesn't allow it and I added just not connected text.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

[image: example of how it works now]

Answer (score 0):

You can use PointerEntered and PointerExited in your textblock to change foreground, If VisualStateManager's PointOver is not working for you.

Comment: I suppose in this case text change will trigger only when user exact hover on textblock not on row in general. Am I wrong?

Comment: if you use like this <TextBlock PointerEntered="" /> , on this case when cursor enters texblock region, it will trigger.

Comment: Yeaah, I'm talking about that - I have 3+ textblocks in a row and <TextBlock PointerEntered="" /> will be triggered when user hover on one of them, but I need behaviour with group color change.

Comment: so, if i understand correctly, you have 3 buttons in a row, if user hovers on one of them, they will all change colors right?

Comment: I have a GridView and in a row there are 3 textblocks and on row hover I'd like to change there color. Currently we made it with code behind but I think there is better approach to do it with just xaml. PS I have added the screen how row looks like.

Answer (score 0):

> I think there is better approach to do it with just xaml.

Sure, you could use [`XamlBehaviors`](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviors) to detect `PointerExited` and  `PointerEntered` event then modify the `Foreground` property.

**Example**

```
<TextBlock
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    FontSize="45"
    Text="Hello"
    >
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerEntered">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Foreground">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
                </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
            </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerExited">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Foreground">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
                </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
            </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

</TextBlock>
```